# VPS SSD vs Dedicated Server performances for Symfony2 app

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, hosting

I would like to host a Symfony2 app and its database (MySQL at the moment).
Shared hosting is not an option for me (not enough RAM, no shell access).

So I wanted to take a dedicated server (with HDD) but I also noticed some less expensive VPS SSD offers while dedicated servers with SSD are out of range for me.

To summarize, I would like to know which config are better to support a high load server, SSD or many RAM + many CPU cores ?

I would also like to know if it would be profitable to take a VPS SSD for the database and the dedicated server for the Symfony app knowing that I can afford it. Will it bring better performance ?

Here are the configs:

**Dedicated server**

- 2To HDD
- i7 2.66 Ghz 4 cores/8 threads
- 16 Go RAM

**VPS SSD**

- 40 Go SSD
- 2 virtual cores 2.4 Ghz
- 8Go RAM

Comment: That's depends on the app you want to host... users...etc

Comment: It's a social network plus some webservices

Comment: Since you are a complete newbie then you might want to find a shared host with ssh access to get started.  There are plenty out there.  Once you get a bit of experience you will realize why this question is getting so many down votes and basically impossible to answer.

Comment: But to answer the question, yes a VPS is a good stard, cheap and you will have full access to the server, which is better for a Symfony app, you can start with this and see later if it really fit your needs.

Comment: @Cerad that's what I did, but got to few ressources to even deploy the website, so I'm looking for another solution.
My question was more about where is the bottleneck between no SSD and few RAM/CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are totally different technologies, which will depend on many factors. RAM and disk storage are very different.

The SSD disks are from 4 to 8 times faster than a SATA HDD, depending on the model.

In a VPS Server, the providers usually host more than 50 virtual servers in a single hardware node. Imagine 50 servers trying to access a SSD disk at once. You will have your access time divided by 50, and the advantage of hosting a VPS with SSD is gone.

If your mysql usage is high, you should consider a server with much RAM. This actually improves MySQL a lot more than a good IO.

Comment: Thanks, I will go for the dedicated server then !

Comment: Yes, that's the best advice.